# What happens when a tick gets overflown?

Tags: .net, datetime, overflow, clock

Topic of this question is date and time calculations.

.NET, as many other platforms, heavily relies on some form of minimal discrete time representation, such as [`DateTime.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx). A tick is an [`Int64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.int64.aspx) type with a max value of roughly 9 * 10<sup>18</sup>.

Assuming .NET clock started ticking from 1-JAN-0001 and following my crude calculations it will take around 30 000 years for a tick to reach `Int64.MaxValue`.

**Question is**: what would be a general approach to deal with such overflow were it to happen next year?

Comment: It is four times worse than you think, the top two bits in the underlying Int64 are used to store DateTime.Kind.  Clearly you don't want to be around when the Y10K problem hits.  And barring major medical break-throughs, and a serious overhaul in the entertainment industry, you won't be.

Comment: @Hans, from a purely academic point of view do you have any articles I can reference that you would recommend that better explain how dates and times are stored (I noticed you talked about the top two bits for Kind) and further the then coming pitfall of the Y2K solution?

Comment: Just look at the Reference Source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, much like the Y2K bug that existed in many COBOL programs, you will have to either shift the root or extend the value. Now, to make that statement less abstract, let's say they shifted the root - so it wouldn't be `1-JAN-0001` anymore, it might be `1-JAN-1001`.

That would cause some problems. And that's how the Y2K bug had to be solved in COBOL so when `2040` rolls around for a lot of shops they are going to have to either change that rollover date again, or extend the value.

In their case, extending the value simply means using a 4-digit year, but in those MF programs it's not always that simple because the data isn't always stored in a database, a lot of times it's on a VSAM file or something.

So, here's what I think will happen, as computing continues to get larger and faster (yet smaller ... hmm) you will find that they will simply extend the value from say `Int64` to `Int128` and leave the root right where it's at. That will have zero adverse effects that I can think of and so it would be the safest approach.